# Access denied over .SSH tunnel to Mysql

Tags: mysql, ssh

I am trying to create an SSH tunnel so that I can write data securely to a remote MySQL database.
I start by setting up the tunnel:

```
ssh username@remote -L 3306:127.0.0.1:3306
```

This gets as far as prompting me for a password and then always gives me the following response:

```
Permission denied, please try again.
```

I know I have the password correct.
I've chnged the password and flushed the privilages and tried again.
The user on MySQL is set to accept from any host.
The firewall and router have rules for the port.

I feel like I'm missing something obvious but cannot work out what, can anyone help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The username/password that is asked is for the user on the *nix-box, not the mysql-username/password.

Make sure you can log in into the server by issuing the following command:

```
ssh username@remote
```

Comment: Thanks, that was it, stupid mistake on my part. Thaks for your help.